# How to create user text input and output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new to coding, but I am need of your help. I need to create a form that allows users to type in a problem for example= should i get a new car?  then in a new box they would list five solutions to their problem(1. save up more, 2. wait, 3.lease, 4. get current car fixed 5. buy a used car. Then once they do that they press submit and random options vanish. Is this possible from Java-script? What would the correct syntax be? Thank you in advance for your help and sorry if it is confusing i will do my best to clarify if needed.

Comment: " I need to create a form" ... Yes, _you_ need to create a form. Where is it? Where is the JS you've tried so far?

Comment: @Teemu From what I understand is that the form would be inserted in the head tag in the html. But truthful i do not know where to start. I looked for demos to help but its all name input and out not what I am looking for.

Comment: A form in `head`? No, in `body`. You've to learn the very basics of [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/fi/docs/Web/HTML) first, then you can have a problem. We're not going to write all the code from scratch for you.

Comment: As I stated I am new at coding. I understand your not going to do that, just looking for help with a specific issue. You telling me to learn basics is not that. But thank you. @Teemu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following example. Hope it will help you:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showOptionBox()
{
    document.getElementById("optionBox").style.display="";
}
function showRandomAnswer()
{
    //alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * (5)) + 1);
    var randomOption=Math.floor(Math.random() * (5)) + 1;
    for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        if(randomOption != i)
        {
            document.getElementById("opt"+i).style.display="none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset><legend>Enter your question:</legend>
        Question:<input type="text" id="question" /><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="showOptionBox();" value="Submit Question">
    </fieldset>

    <div id="optionBox" style="display: none">
        <fieldset><legend>Enter your options:</legend>
        <div id="opt1">Option 1:<input type="text"/></div><br>
        <div id="opt2">Option 2:<input type="text"/></div><br>
        <div id="opt3">Option 3:<input type="text"/></div><br>
        <div id="opt4">Option 4:<input type="text"/></div><br>
        <div id="opt5">Option 5:<input type="text"/></div><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="showRandomAnswer();" value="Show Random Answer"/>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. This is perfect, thank you for your effort in showing your code. It means a lot! @sAm no i can get a better understanding of how this works.

Comment: is there a way to add CSS to this? I have tried however I see no changes and it says user agent stylesheet.

Comment: after a little research and trial and error the CSS is working.Thanks again for your help.